# Can mssql_query detect inserting error?

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to detect inserting result.

When I tried to insert with `INSERT INTO table (1,2,'t')` this will result in inserting error because of the third column of my table is decimal type,but mssql_query will return true.

but when I tested with `INSET INTO table (1,2,'t')` this will return false,like it should.

Why the first statement returning true? and how can we check that it is an error not true!!

Comment: Is this sql-server? or MySQL? If it is MySQL, you can use `mysql_error()` to print out any error returned from your `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Does a row actually get inserted in the first statement?

Comment: mssql_query is for sqlserver :),btw I'm really frustrated. How can this return true....WTH
ps.no record was inserted

Comment: Not sure if this helps but try adding these lines to your PHP code after doing a `mssql_connect()`: `mssql_min_error_severity(0); mssql_min_message_severity(10);`

Comment: DEfine what you mean, return true. Do you mean it passes the syntax check?

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax is:

```
insert into table_name (column_name1, column_name2, ..) 
VALUES (value_of_column1, value_of_column2, ..)
```

As you already know ordering part is not required, but i highly suggest you to do ordering first and then give values to it.

mysql_query return false on error and you can get error by using mysql_error function.

And keep this in your mind that you should surround values by quotations only when you are filling columns with type of varchar/char/date/datetime..

Other types like boolean, int, decimal and.. should be provided without quotations.

Hope it solve your problem ;)

Comment: I do use a full column assign in my code the above is just a quick demonstrate.
The point here is mssql_query() haven't recognized datatype error as a fail insert